# Incomplete source code in plainbox-provider-snappy repository

Tags: snap, repository, git

For the purpose of adding new test cases for CDTS I'm following the official document (https://checkbox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snappy.html) to git clone plainbox-provider-snappy repository.

But the `bin`, `data` and `units` directories mentioned in the official documentation are not in this repository.

Browsing the source tree from https://git.launchpad.net/plainbox-provider-snappy/tree/, I still find no key directories.

Could you help me to get the full source code of plainbox-provider-snappy repository? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned about bin/ data/ and units/, maybe the repository you are searching is:
https://code.launchpad.net/plainbox-provider-checkbox/